# Creating a bitmap from pattern and foreground and background colours

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I want to create bitmaps from a graphics.brushstyles pattern and two colour integers and load them into an ImageList.  I am using Delphi 2007 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  The code I have used is shown.  I would expect this to at least compile but get the following errors:

```
[DCC Error] QuickUnitGraph.pas(2912): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Create'
[DCC Error] QuickUnitGraph.pas(2913): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SetSize'
[DCC Error] QuickUnitGraph.pas(2914): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Canvas'
[DCC Error] QuickUnitGraph.pas(2920): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBitmap' and 'tagBITMAP'
```

On further investigation, I find that Delphi thinks the variable Bmp is a windows.TagBITMAP which has a different set of properties and methods.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
procedure CreateBitMap(il:TImageList; Pattern, Foreground, Background:integer);

var
  Bmp: TBitmap;

begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create(nil);
  Bmp.SetSize(50,50);
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := TBrushStyle(Pattern);
  Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := TColor(Foreground);
  Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := TColor(Background);
  il.Add(Bmp);
end;
```

Comment: Make sure you list `Graphics` unit **after** `Windows` in `uses` clause.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: please add your comment as an answer so it can get accepted as solution.